# Map user input to a data frame and return NA if the user input is not found in the data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, tidyr

I have a data frame with two columns "A" and "B". I created a function that works as mentioned below:

If X (user entered value) is found in column A, then return the X value found in column A and it's corresponding value in B column.

Here's my code:

```
myfunction <- function(x) {
  r<- with(my_dataframe, my_dataframe[A %in% x, c("A", "B")])
  return(data.frame(r))
}
```

I want to tweak this in such a way that if user input (value for X) doesn't appear in column A, return that value and NA for column B.

Example:

```
A  B
1  A12
2  F1222
```

If the values for X are 1, 5. I want the output to look like this --

```
1 A12
5 NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myfunction <- function(x) {
   r<- with(my_dataframe, my_dataframe[A %in% x, c("A", "B")])
   if(!nrow(r)) data.frame(A=x,B=NA) else data.frame(r)
 }
> myfunction(3)
  A  B
1 3 NA
> myfunction(2)
  A     B
2 2 F1222
```

edit to allow vectors:

```
my=function(x){
  s=subset(data,A==x)
  m=x%in%s$A
  if(all(m)) s else   rbind(s,cbind(A=x[!m],B=NA))
}

 my(1)
  A   B
1 1 A12
> my(1:10)
    A     B
1   1   A12
2   2 F1222
3   3  <NA>
4   4  <NA>
5   5  <NA>
6   6  <NA>
7   7  <NA>
8   8  <NA>
9   9  <NA>
10 10  <NA>
> my(4)
  A  B
1 4 NA

my(c(1,3.11))
     A    B
1 1.00  A12
2 3.11 <NA>
```

Comment: m<- c("1","3.11") myfunction(m) only returns the value for 1 and no results for 3.11 
@Onyambu

Comment: You never specified you were to input a vector

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be to first find `matched rows` using condition as `matched = my_dataframe$A==x`.

Now, there are any matched rows found use `matched` value to return corresponding rows. Otherwise create a row with `NA` value for `B`.

```
myfunction <- function(x) {
  r <- data.frame()
  matched = my_dataframe$A %in% x
  if(sum(matched) > 0){
      r<- with(my_dataframe, my_dataframe[matched, c("A", "B")])
  } else{
      r<-data.frame(A = x, B = NA)
  } 
  return(r)
}

#Test
myfunction(2)
#   A   B
# 2 2 A34
myfunction(11)
#    A  B
# 1 11 NA
```

**Edited:** Based on latest feedback from `OP`, I think `dplyr::left_join` will do the trick for him as:

```
a <- 1
dplyr::left_join(data.frame(A=a), my_dataframe, by="A")
#   A   B
# 1 1 A21


a <- c(2,3,12,34,45)
dplyr::left_join(data.frame(A=a), my_dataframe, by="A")
#    A    B
# 1  2  A34
# 2  3 D345
# 3 12 <NA>
# 4 34 <NA>
# 5 45 <NA>
```

## Data

```
my_dataframe <- data.frame(A = 1:4, 
              B=c("A21", "A34", "D345", "E45"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: the only issue I see is this would not work if you pass a list to myfunction. Say for example - myfunction(2,11). Any thoughts? @MKR

Comment: @Hariesh You can change the line as `matched =  my_dataframe$A %in% x`

Comment: m<- c("1","3.11")
myfunction(m) only returns the value for 1 and no results for 3.11
@MKR

Comment: @Hariesh I think, all you need can be taken care by `dplyr::left_join`. Have a look at my updated answer. Perhaps 1 line will do the trick for you.